# Compiling .Net with "Any CPU architecture" but preferring 32bit in configuration

Tags: .net, cpu-architecture

Is it possible to compile a .NET program with "Any CPU architecture" and set "prefer 32bit" in the app.config or command line (I don't want it to always run in 32bit mode, only when the user wants it)?

Comment: Why does it matter?  Unless you have dependencies that cannot run in one of the two architectures what difference does it make which it's loaded under?

Comment: Because my application may need to load 32bit dlls... my user adds his plugins to my application.

Comment: Do you actually *need* 64-bit *at all*? It's usually unnecessary unless you actually code specifically for 64-bit, or there is no 32-bit version of a 3rd party DLL to use for some reason (or user plugins in your case).

Comment: I do. He can have several instances of this application. To one instance he can add 32bit plugins to to another 64bit plugins. I'd rather not give him 2 versions of the application (one for each cpu-architecture).

Comment: Can you make a helper executable that would make the application start in 32-bit mode? That's pretty much as simple as making a 32-bit project that executes `Main` from your main project.

Comment: I tried to start the process from a 32bit "command line" console but it didn't help... should there be a difference?

Comment: Yes, the command line starts a new process. Instead, you want to run the application in your own 32-bit process - literally just adding your main assembly as a reference and calling `Program.Main(args)`.

Comment: It is trivially changed with Corflags.exe.  That's however an SDK utility, not exactly what an end-user can be expected to have access to.  Building two versions of your release-built EXE is the next trivial solution.